# Continue HTML form filling after closing and re-opening again

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, session

There is any way to temporary save filled data in HTML form? I mean If I have form like this:

```
Name    [ John  ]
Email   [       ]
Address [       ]
```

That after closing window and re-entering again to www.domain.com/form.php `John` value still be entered in `Name` text-box?

Should I use `SESSIONS` for It? Or should I insert every entered field to database automatically? Have you any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've tried following with Chrome / Microsoft Edge, but unsuccessfully, filled fields not saving after refreshing browser. Maybe something did wrong?

```
  <script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Store
    localStorage.setItem("FirstName", "Hitesh");
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("FirstName").value = localStorage.getItem("FirstName");
} else {
    document.getElementById("FirstName").value = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
  </script>

<input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" class="field-style" placeholder="First Name" required />
```

Comment: you can use localStorage to set the values and then JS to reset them if they reopen the page. note - don't use sessionStaorage since that will be cleared when they close the page and then reload it.

Comment: Do you need the data to be saved on the server? If not, use `localStorage`.

Comment: @gavgrif thank you for suggestion, but I can't achieve It correctly, updated my question with what I've tried with `localStorage`, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: @Xufox no care, just looking for anyway how to achieve It, that after closing browser users could resume filling forms.

Answer (score 1):

here is example of form with autofill you can use localstorage

```
 <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" class="field-style" placeholder="First Name" required onchange="save()"/> 

 <script>
// Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if(localStorage.getItem("FirstName")!=""){

    }else{
    // Store
        localStorage.setItem("FirstName", "Hitesh");
    }
    // Retrieve
    document.getElementById("FirstName").value = localStorage.getItem("FirstName");
} else {
    document.getElementById("FirstName").value = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
 function save(){
    var name = document.getElementById('FirstName').value;
  localStorage.setItem("FirstName", name);
 }    
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but It not worked for me. Updated my question with details.

Comment: Hi i found problem you have to put script at the end of the form

Comment: Now after refreshing browser It Always keep word `Hitesh`, how could I change It that It returned what user entered before refreshing browser instead of static text?

Comment: Still returning `Hitesh` after refreshing I need to save It without clicking any buttons.

Comment: if you dont click on button how the form send data ??

Comment: See now i updated the code with onchange event so now when you type in text box it save data in localstorage

Comment: Thank you with `onchange="save()"` It working. Is it possible to make this function dynamic? I have over 150 fields of which values should be saved. So for now I need to create over 150 functions. Would be nice to achieve It dynamically. Else still I need to use this part? `}else{
    // Store
        localStorage.setItem("FirstName", "Hitesh");
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Well preferably use cookie to store form field data on local storage because it can easily get handled via JavaScript (Consider that storing very private data is not a good idea even the cookie expires quit soon).

And in order to set the cookie immediately after filling the field you can use onFocusOut event listener for fields. When user focused out of each field set the value of the input field on cookie.